# Swipe event that work with live()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements on a page that are loaded dynamically, but I also need to be able to swipe on these divs.

I searched for jQuery swipe events, and found [touchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin). This is nice because it's cross browser, but it does not allow me to use `.on()` or `.live()`, so the dynamic elements aren't accounted for.

Here's an example of what I mean, http://jsfiddle.net/wUkZq/

The only way I could get swiping to work on the dynamic elements was to attach the swipe event to the parent. Problem is, I don't want the parent to be swipeable. In the example, if you create a few elements with the `a` link, then try and swipe within `.content`, it will return the text of all elements, which is not what I'm wanting, as swiping should not be allowed in the parent.

Is there a better way to do this, or a better plugin? Ideally, I'd like to not use a plugin, but pure JS, but I can't find a good example of calculating when the person is actually swiping instead of some other event (i.e. scrolling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply assigning each swipeable element a specific class, then checking for that class in the `swipe` event handler? It's quite a common trick for such cases, I suppose. For example:

```
swipeLeft: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
  var $target = $(event.target);  
  if (! $target.hasClass('sw')) {
    return false;
  }
  alert($target.text());
}
```

Here's a [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wUkZq/3/) illustrating the concept.

Comment: I originally had something like this, but I didn't think it was the best way to do it.